# Nilpotent subalgebras and ideals

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I believe these questions are trivial, but I still need some help.

Consider $\mathfrak{h}$ Lie subalgebra of the real $n-$dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Is there a non-trivial ideal $J$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ containing $\mathfrak{h}$?

Another question: If $\mathfrak{h}$ is nilpotent (still subalgebra, non-necessarily an ideal), may I consider $\mathfrak{h}$ contained in the nilrad of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: Regarding the first question, are you familiar with the concept of simple Lie algebras, and know some examples? That should provide you with counterexamples.

Comment: For the second question, take any element of any Lie algebra and consider its (one-dimensional) span. That is a subalgebra. It is nilpotent. If all of those were contained in the nilradical ...

Comment: These are good counterexamples, thank you.